# Given a CFG and one of its nonterminals $v$ determine if there exists a sentential form beginning with $v$?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, decision-problem

I am supposed to find an algorithm solving the following problem:

Given a CFG $\;G=(V_N, V_T, R, S)$ and a nonterminal $v \in V_N$ determine if there exists a sentential form which begins with $v$.

I don't know anything about the form of the grammar and I can't convert it into Chomsky's form as it would introduce new nonterminals and possibly remove $v$. Where do I start with this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you been exposed to the concept of transitive closure and the algorithm used to compute it?

Comment: To me, it looks like $v$ needs to be the *first* symbol along some derivation.

Comment: Hint, instead of checking if $v$ is the first symbol of some sentential form, try collecting every non-terminal that is the first symbol of some sentential form.

Comment: @rici no, I don't think I have.  
"Sentential form" is the term I was missing, going to edit the question. Also thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Have you heard of FIRST sets?

Comment: I think the solution is clearer when you write out the derivation chain; "sentential form" is a nice phrase but to use the concept you need to look at derivations. How do you derive a sentential form which starts $\nu$? Surely there must be some previous sentential form in the derivation which starts with $\mu$ where $\mu\to\nu\alpha$, no? And so on until you reach $S$. Do you see how that implies a chain of relations? At which point the use of the transitive closure algorithm should be evident.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've looked it up now. What if we tried finding modified FIRST(S), where we would not include any terminals?

Comment: You can modify the algorithm computing FIRST to your problem, I believe. You should try to work it out.